# Greasemonkey - regex in javascript to change links

Tags: javascript, regex, url, greasemonkey, replace

I'm trying to change the url's of a webpage on the fly using greasemonkey.

**Example of subject to be changed :**

```
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://site.com/goto/http_rapidshare_com_files_1401021221_SK_RG_X_FLAWL3SS_part01_rar/11609/107" rel="nofollow">http://rapidshare.com/files/1401021221/SK.RG.X.FLAWL3SS.part01.rar</a></p>
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://site.com/goto/http_rapidshare_com_files_3525685465_1_3_3_8_com_Parenthood_2010_S03E07_720p_HDTV_X264_DIMENSION_mkv/11598/51" rel="nofollow">http://rapidshare.com/files/3525685465/1-3-3-8.com_Parenthood.2010.S03E07.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv</a></p>
```

**GreaseMonkey Script:**

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
  var el = els[i];
   el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/<p><a rel="nofollow" href=".*?" rel="nofollow">(.*?)<\/a><\/p>/img, '<p><a rel="nofollow" href="$1" rel="nofollow">$1</a><p>');
}
```

**Desired Output :**

```
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://rapidshare.com/files/1401021221/SK.RG.X.FLAWL3SS.part01.rar" rel="nofollow">http://rapidshare.com/files/1401021221/SK.RG.X.FLAWL3SS.part01.rar</a></p>
<p><a rel="nofollow" href="http://rapidshare.com/files/3525685465/1-3-3-8.com_Parenthood.2010.S03E07.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv" rel="nofollow">http://rapidshare.com/files/3525685465/1-3-3-8.com_Parenthood.2010.S03E07.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv</a></p>
```

Basically, the regex above should change the href (**http://site.com/goto/http_rapidshare_com_files_1401021221_SK_RG_X_FLAWL3SS_part01_rar/11609/107**) to the visible text of the url (**http://rapidshare.com/files/1401021221/SK.RG.X.FLAWL3SS.part01.rar**) but for some reason it doesn't, any idea why?

Thank you all!
regards,
Lob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target the links a little more precisely.    Regex is very brittle when trying to parse HTML; the slightest variation in even order or whitespace can break it.

Fortunately, regex does not appear to be needed in this case.

This should work (untested):

```
var rapidShareLinks = document.querySelectorAll ("a[href*='rapidshare']");
for (var J = rapidShareLinks.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
    var rsLink  = rapidShareLinks[J];
    rsLink.href = rsLink.textContent;
}
```

Comment: @Brock, lol. haven't seen in the question, that valid links are already present on the page :D

Answer (score 1):

*This was an answer to the first edition of question*

*For the second edition - just use **Brock**'s answer (chosen)*

---

This should work:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("A");
for(var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) {
    var el = els[i];
    el.href = el.href.replace(/http:\/\/(.)+?\/(.)+?\//, '').replace(/\/.+/g, '').replace('http_', 'http://').replace(/_files_(\d+?)_/, '/files/$1/').replace(/_/g, '.');
}
```

Notice that i'm only matching `<a>` tags, and parse their `href` attributes directly.

Also, because its a sample script, it does not care about **other** links on the page, that might get ruined in process ;)

Comment: Thanks for your code but I doesn't work correctly with all links, in order to work it must get the visible part of the url and make it the href. I've updated the question with a new link that doesn't work.